# Access the same file for read and write random position

Tags: java, randomaccessfile

Start by saying that I have not great experience in Java and I've done a lot of research. I would please ask you a specific question.
Thank you

I need to open a file for reading and writing from which I read and write a 512-byte blocks.
The file is fixed length and the information to be written will overlap with other existing.
For example, I read the first 512 bytes of the file and if it contains certain values write a block 512 to position 2048.
I tried using `FileInputStream` and `FileOutputStream` but every time I open with `FileOutputStream` the contents of the file are deleted.
It can be done with Java?

Roberto

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a [`FileChannel`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/channels/FileChannel.html); it allows random access to any part of a file, in read, write or any combination of both.

Example:

```
final Path path = Paths.get("path/to/the/file");
final FileChannel channel = FileChannel.open(path, relevantOptions);
```

Optionally, after that, you can use the `.map()` method.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I did not know the FileChannel. However I see some examples on the internet that I first have to open the file with RandomAccessFile.

Comment: That was the case with Java 6; not with Java 7+, see my code sample.